# Is there a way to convert a formatted duration value into a text value?

Tags: numbers

I am trying to convert duration values into the specific format I need for subtitle timings: 00:00:00,000 - leading zeroes for hour, minute and second, and a comma separating seconds and milliseconds instead of a decimal point.

The formatting options for durations do not allow this level of customisation. I can do it via a function in a few different ways (concatenation, substitution etc) if I can get the formatted duration value (e.g. 0:00:00.000) as a string. Trying to use various text functions on the duration value just returns an empty string, and functions like T and PLAINTEXT do not convert other data types into a string.

Is there a way to convert the formatted duration into a text value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert a duration value represented in `h:mm:ss.ms` to a text value formatted as `h:mm:ss,ms` in Numbers by formating the original duration value with the Automatic Units duration data format and using the SUBSTITUTE() function.

To format the original duration with the Automatic Units duration data format, select the cell with the original duration and click on Format > Cell > Duration > Automatic Units in the sidebar Numbers menus as shown in the picture below while the formula in cell B1 would be

```
SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",",")
```

[image]

Depending on the actual durations you have, you may need to develop that formula a bit further to make sure the outcome is always in the `h:mm:ss,ms` format.

For example, in case some of the durations are less than one hour, then the  following formula could be used:

```
IF(DUR2HOURS(A1)<1,"0:","") & SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",",")
```

Comment: Not sure why it only works with the default formatting, but with a little tweaking (many of the timings are under one minute), this worked perfectly. Thank you so much!